# In dataframe / data.table, set variable within a group to one under certain conditions on values in the previous column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe / data.table of the following form:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(id = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4), rep("c", 4), rep("d", 4), rep("e", 4)), 
                switch = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                same = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                year = rep(1980:1983, 5))
#> DT
#    id switch same year switch_update
# 1:  a      0    0 1980             0
# 2:  a      0    0 1981             0
# 3:  a      0    0 1982             0
# 4:  a      1    1 1983             1
# 5:  b      0    0 1980             0
# 6:  b      1    1 1981             1
# 7:  b      0    1 1982             1
# 8:  b      0    0 1983             0
# 9:  c      0    0 1980             0
#10:  c      1    1 1981             1
#11:  c      0    1 1982             1
#12:  c      0    1 1983             1
#13:  d      0    1 1980             0
#14:  d      0    1 1981             0
#15:  d      0    1 1982             0
#16:  d      0    1 1983             0
#17:  e      0    0 1980             0
#18:  e      0    1 1981             0
#19:  e      0    1 1982             0
#20:  e      0    0 1983             0
```

The variable "id" identifies a pair of individuals, "same" if they are in the same location, "switch" identifies if in a given year, one of the individuals switches to the other's location. 
I would like to create a variable "switch_update" that summarizes the switching history. It is supposed to be one if a swich occured and for all time periods after the switch in which the individuals are in the same location and zero otherwise.

I believe that I came up with a solution that builds on data.tables "shift" function and updating a copy of the variable "switch" by iterating over the years by the "id" variable. 
It is quite clumsy and I believe that there might be a more standard way to achieve what I want.

Here is my code:

```
# Order the data set after id and year
setkey(DT, "id", "year")

# make a copy of the switch variable
DT[, switch_copy := switch]

# DT

# Now, update the variable switch copy by iterating over the years: 

for(i in 1:length(unique(DT[, (year)]))){
    DT[, switch_copy := ifelse(shift(switch_copy, 1, type = "lag") == 1 & same == 1, 1, switch_copy), by = "id"][
     , switch_copy := ifelse(is.na(switch_copy), 0, switch_copy)]
}

#     id switch same year switch_update switch_copy
# 1:  a      0    0 1980             0           0
# 2:  a      0    0 1981             0           0
# 3:  a      0    0 1982             0           0
# 4:  a      1    1 1983             1           1
# 5:  b      0    0 1980             0           0
# 6:  b      1    1 1981             1           1
# 7:  b      0    1 1982             1           1
# 8:  b      0    0 1983             0           0
# 9:  c      0    0 1980             0           0
#10:  c      1    1 1981             1           1
#11:  c      0    1 1982             1           1
#12:  c      0    1 1983             1           1
#13:  d      0    1 1980             0           0
#14:  d      0    1 1981             0           0
#15:  d      0    1 1982             0           0
#16:  d      0    1 1983             0           0
#17:  e      0    0 1980             0           0
#18:  e      0    1 1981             0           0
#19:  e      0    1 1982             0           0
#20:  e      0    0 1983             0           0
```

Is there a more standard way to do this, possibly using built-in functions?

Comment: maybe `DT[, sw_upd := cumsum(switch), .(id, same)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function which returns 1 for all the rows after a `switch` happened

```
switch_happened <- function(switch) {
   switch_done <- switch == 1
   if (any(switch_done)) 
     as.integer(seq_along(switch) >= which.max(switch_done))
   else 0L
}
```

and apply it by group

```
library(data.table)
DT[, switch_update := switch_happened(switch), .(id, same)]
DT

#    id switch same year switch_update
# 1:  a      0    0 1980             0
# 2:  a      0    0 1981             0
# 3:  a      0    0 1982             0
# 4:  a      1    1 1983             1
# 5:  b      0    0 1980             0
# 6:  b      1    1 1981             1
# 7:  b      0    1 1982             1
# 8:  b      0    0 1983             0
# 9:  c      0    0 1980             0
#10:  c      1    1 1981             1
#11:  c      0    1 1982             1
#12:  c      0    1 1983             1
#13:  d      0    1 1980             0
#14:  d      0    1 1981             0
#15:  d      0    1 1982             0
#16:  d      0    1 1983             0
#17:  e      0    0 1980             0
#18:  e      0    1 1981             0
#19:  e      0    1 1982             0
#20:  e      0    0 1983             0
```

Comment: This is an very elegant solution, thank you very much!